# Звонок из приложения по нажатию кнопки

Tags: android, android-intent

Написал следующий код, который по кнопке делает звонок на указанный телефон.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + phc));
startActivity(intent);
```

На Samsung Note 3 код отрабатывает.
На Xiaomi Note 4 код не срабатывает!

В чем проблема? Как совершить звонок по нажатию кнопки в данном случае?

Comment: Там АПИ другое у меня друг это делал. Ищи документацию по прошивке.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Xiaomi Note 4 - девайс с Android 6 на борту. Начиная с Android 6 Marshmallow введены Runtime permissions. Теперь написать разрешение в манифесте недостаточно. Разрешение `ACTION_CALL` относится к `dangerous permissions`, поэтому вам его надо запросить в рантайме. Подробнее почитайте [в этой статье](https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/278945/)

Или же смените `ACTION_CALL` на `АCTION_DIAL`. Но тогда не будет звонка, будет переход в звонилку с уже вбитым номером